# jQuery Buttons - Unusual CSS Styling

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

Within my PhoneGap application I have the following form button:

```
<input type="button" value="Proceed" id="proceed">
```

I have in my stylesheet the following to overwrite the original jQuery mobile:

```
#proceed {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50%;
}
```

If I don't set opacity to 1 then the background colour is washed out and not much use. When I set it to 1 however, the "background" colour of red appears over the text (reflected by the "value" in html) "Proceed" which is the problem here.

Further, despite having width set to 50%, the button seems to hold a width of 100% with an internal box of 50% width in red. I am not sure where this internal box effect has come from - it must be a jQuery feature as it is not in my code.

This looks unusual - how can I style the button as a whole? Or more simply, how can I have the value of the button appear on top of the background color?

Comment: The css added does not seem to affect the button (html) provided - Please add a [mcve] to your question

Comment: @ochi - apologies - had snipped the wrong line of html. Thanks

Comment: Well, the edit is an improvement but still not a [mcve] - in the question, you make references to a label (which is not present), then to an internal box (nope, not there either).  Help us, help you! Otherwise, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: It sounds like there is more to this problem than you have presented.  As ochi suggests, you should provide enough code to reproduce your issue or it is unlikely anyone will be able to assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code:

```css
#proceed {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Proceed" id="proceed">
```

If you inspect the funky button (right click on it and select "Inspect" or "Inspect element"), you'll see that jQuery mobile wraps the button in extra html:

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
  Proceed
  <input type="button" value="Proceed" id="proceed">
</div>
```

To change its color, you have to change its theme using `data-theme`:

```
<input type="button" value="Proceed" data-theme="a">
```

By default, jQuery Mobile has a few themes built in: white (`data-theme="a"`), black (`data-theme="b"`), [etc](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/api/themes.html). Red isn't one of them, so I guess you have to create a theme ([using their web site](https://themeroller.jquerymobile.com/)) and then add the theme's generated CSS files to your page.